SettingWithCopyWarning/Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
How can I rewrite the following in order to avoid the below warning.
I am trying to add a new column to dataframe which basically is diff() of a column from same dataframe.
df['diff_column'] = df['column'].diff()
I am unsure of how to use .loc for this.
Warning seen:
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
